# Successive Bounces of Ball Paradox

Tags: paradoxes

Assume a Ball is bouncing and is travelling in the horizontal direction at constant horizontal velocity v.

Also assume that after each successive bounce, the ball is is in the air for half the time of the previous bounce.

We therefore conclude that each bounce covers half the distance of the previous bounce.

If the initial bounce is 1m, how far will the ball travel?

Method 1:
Each bounce is half the previous bounce, giving an infinite geometric series, evaluating to a travel distance of 2m.

Method 2:
The ball is travelling at a constant velocity so the ball will go on forever.

What is the explanation behind this apparant paradox?

Comment: How many times will the ball have bounced after twice the duration of the first bounce? What happens after this time?

Comment: That's not consistent with your question. You specified that _the ball is is in the air for half the time of the previous bounce_; in your comment, it appears that you let the ball bounce for time $t/2$ twice, instead of once $t/2$ and once $t/4$.

Comment: To start with, you only want to count the horizontal distance covered whilst the ball is in the air (you haven't explicitly said that, though). Secondly, the horizontal distance covered whilst the ball is in the air is bounded above by 2m and you can get arbitrarily close to this by measuring the distance covered over a longer time. This is just a rewording of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes

Comment: You give absolutely no argument or reasoning for method $2$. So it's not surprising that it is the one that is wrong.

Comment: But Method 1 is wrong.

Comment: Argument for Method 2:  Speed = Distance/time.  Distance = Speed*Time.  Speed is constant.  There is no upper bound on time, and therefore no upper bound on distance.

Comment: But, you believe (I assume, because you stated it) that the sum of the geometric series is finite. So you must believe that an infinite sum of finite numbers can be finite. So why do you think that method 2 is in any way correct? If I've understood your argument correctly then you are saying "An infinite sum of finite numbers must be infinite."

Comment: My argument for method 2 is like this.  Let's assume velocity is 2m/s.  Distance = 2*t.  After 3 seconds, Distance = 2*3 = 6m, exceeding 2.

Comment: @Chris, there has to be some problem with the initial assumptions. "constant horizontal velocity" and "each bounce is half time => each bouce = half distance".

Comment: I think the problem is that the ball can't keep moving in the air beyond 2 seconds. Assume the velocity is 1m/s. After 1 second it has travelled 1m. Now the next bounce takes 0.5 seconds and it travels a further 0.5m, right? So after 2 seconds it has travelled 2m. But now the bounces are so small that it's rolling. Yes, the horizontal speed is still 1m/s but it's no longer covering that distance whilst in the air. So the total horizontal distance covered whilst in the air is 2m.

Comment: If you're worried about that problem, this one might give you bad dreams: There are point-like billiard balls of equal mass on the $x$ axis, one at every coordinate $2^{-n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$. You give the first one a push to make it move in the negative $x$ direction with unit velocity. It comes to a halt as it bumps into the next one and sets it going. After one time unit, all the balls have been bumped and come to a halt again -- but where did the energy and momentum go that you'd imparted to the first ball?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "paradox" arises from the fact that both 1 and 2 are correct, in the following sense.

The total horizontal distance covered whilst the ball is **in the air** is 2m. But after 2 seconds (assuming a horizontal speed of 1m/s)  2m has been covered whilst the ball is in the air and from now on the ball is rolling on the ground. The total horizontal distance covered is unbounded but to get the unbounded distance you have to (also) consider the distance travelled whilst the ball is **on the ground**.

I have made some assumptions here, like the (vertical) height of each bounce is strictly less than the height of the bounce before it but this usually happens in real life (on earth, anyway).

Comment: You could add the assumption that the height of each bounce is constant and it is only the frequency of each bounce which increases. I'm not sure what could be said about the ball's position after 2 seconds in that case, I'm not even sure that the question would make sense.

I think the main point to this question and answer is that you have to think about what assumptions or restrictions you're putting on the problem and this problem appears difficult because not all the assumptions have been stated.

Comment: Thanks Sam, your answer appears to have resolved the apparent paradox.

Comment: Could it be resolved if the balls height is assumed to be fixed for all bounces?

Comment: I think we'd need to figure out what assumptions we would be using, we obviously wouldn't be modelling real life if we allow the height of each bounce to be fixed so what are we doing, what assumptions do we have and what reasoning is valid. What axioms are we using? It's possible that those two assumptions (constant horizontal velocity and constant height for each bounce) would lead to a contradiction and that no meaningful answer could be obtained, if this were the case then it wouldn't be possible to resolve the paradox as in an inconsistent system every statement is true (or provable).

Answer (score 1):

This is a paraphrasing of [Zeno's paradoxes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes)

To explain a bit further, In say the ball travels at velocity $v$, then in $t$ time, it has traveled a distance $x \cdot t$. However, each bounce, it travels half the distance, so let total distance be $D$, however, then total time is $D/v$ which is a contradiction, you said it goes on for ever, not a fixed amount of time. Yes, however, in that fixed amount of time, it travels a distance $D$.